# How can I set font size for all activities in Android programming

Tags: android

I'm building an android application thatI need to have a seek bar in the first activity to use it to change the font size for all texts for all other  activities that follow (approximetally 8 activities}.Can someone pls help??

Answer (score 1):

The Solution is: You can't. But there is a work around(not sure though worth a try). You create a base activity and extend the base activity in all your activities (approx. 8 as you say). Then you can use the `for` loop kind of thing to set fonts to every text in the activitites in the onResume() of the Base Activity.

Something like this:

```
public static void setViewGroupTypeface(ViewGroup container, Typeface typeface) {
        final int children = container.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < children; i++) 
            View child = container.getChildAt(i);

            if (child instanceof TextView) {
                setTextViewTypeface((TextView) child, typeface);
            } else if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                setViewGroupTypeface((ViewGroup) child, typeface);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void setTextViewTypeface(TextView textView, Typeface typeface) {
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);
    }
```

Where you call the `setViewGroupTypeface` method with rootView of the activity as the viewGroup along with the typeFace.